# while updating class name of an element why "this" keyword is needed?

Tags: javascript

I'm referring to example

```js
// Get the container element
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myDIV");

// Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Style the active class (and buttons on mouse-over) */
.active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn active">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
</div>
```

In this to replace active class to nil, `current[0].className` is used as below

```
current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
```

But to add classname, `this` keyword is used

```
this.className += " active";
```

Why can't I add new classname as below

`current[0].className += " active";`   ?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: It's generally best to avoid the advertising laiden, low quality tutorial mill that is W3Schools. [We have a modern API for manipulating classes on an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) which is over a decade old now, even IE10 supports it!

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions @Quentin I will keep those in mind for future queries

Comment: Do that, but also click *Edit* and *fix this one*

Comment: done, please let me know if this is fine. Also I'm begineer to JS and web development so it will be good to teach us rather than straight away down voting and discouraging. I am sure you also did these mistakes in your earlier days. Thanks for understanding genuine concerns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `this` in your current context is the clicked button. Another way to do it is with `e.target.classList.add('active');`, but before doing so you should pass `e` to the callback function parameter like that

```
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    e.target.classList.add('active');
  });
```

Comment: I appreciate that :) As "this" in JS can be a lot of things, it may worth for you to read about is as you may encounter behavior which you will consider as very strange until you get used to it :)